# Two webapps which share data and session

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I have already written one web app using java,spring, and tomcat8 as server and now I want to write other but this one has to interact with the previous. It has to share some data from database and session(I mean if user login in one app he doesn't need to login in other app). What is the best way to implement this ?

Comment: Looking at http://www.josso.org/ might be worth. Single sign on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to solve this. Tomcat supports clustered see: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/cluster-howto.html 
But as Dimitrisli already wrote it may be the easiest solution to have a look at spring-session (see: http://projects.spring.io/spring-session/).

I am using this in a project of mine and it works pretty good, but you have to be aware that right now the default serialization scheme is "ObjecStream" which is the regular java serialization. So you can't use different versions of a class on your servers that you are putting into the session. This would lead to a deserialization exception. But I am pretty sure the same problem may occur if you use tomcat/jboss7glassfish/etc. clustering.

If you want to be free in your service deployments, you may use one of the clustering solutions and only store the minimal information that is necessary, like the sessionID and then use something like redis or whatever DB solution you like  to store the session related data in a more "class-evolution" friendly format like for example json. This leads to more work for you, but also much more flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly broad, but generally speaking, you'd just use the same database configuration for both applications, and you can use session replication to share sessions between servers. Tomcat has some built-in functionality to do that, but you should also consider [Spring Session](http://projects.spring.io/spring-session/), which hooks into the servlet filter chain to externalize sessions in a cross-platform style.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few solutions for session clustering but since you are in the Spring ecosystem take a look at the newly launched [Spring Session project](http://projects.spring.io/spring-session/) which makes this task much easier and is also webapp provider agnostic.

Answer (score 0):

Generally sharing sessions is not recommended, for database sharing use JNDI and get the objects. If login is to be handled in your case use Single SignON.